# Array inside JSONArray iteration in java

Tags: java, json, arrays

My Json is:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "Asset": [
            {
                "id": 2461,
                "name": "TestAsset7771",
                "model_name": "TestModel777",
                "serial_number": "TestAsset7771",
                "current_data": {
                    "timestamp": "",
                    "name": "Temperature",
                    "value": "?"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2448,
                "model_id": 1229,
                "name": "TestAsset777",
                "model_name": "TestModel777",
                "serial_number": "TestAsset777",
                "current_data": {
                    "timestamp": "",
                    "name": "Temperature",
                    "value": "?"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My code is:

```
JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject(jsonObj.toString());
JSONObject innerObject = outerObject.getJSONObject("Response");
JSONArray jsonArray = innerObject.getJSONArray("Asset");
for (int i = 0, size = jsonArray.length(); i < size; i++)
{
    JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String[] elementNames = JSONObject.getNames(objectInArray)
    for (String elementName : elementNames)
    {
       String value = objectInArray.getString(elementName);
       System.out.printf("name=%s, value=%s\n", elementName, value);
    }
}
```

For inner array - ie current data, am getting values as:

> name=current_data,
>   value={"timestamp":"","name":"Temperature","value":"?"}

How can i put another inner array so that i can get values of 
"timestamp":"",    "name":"Temperature",    "value":"?" in separate variables instead of complete JSON

Comment: Uh, "value" is a map.  Extract the entries from the map.

Comment: value is json again..

Comment: If the above JSON listing is accurate and you used a plain JSON parser, the value of "current_data" will be a Map.  For the particular JSON parser you're using the form of Map would be a JSONObject.  Access the elements just as you'd access any other Map.

Answer (score 0):

"value" is another jason object, so you can just call "getJasonObject()" to obtain the item and then proceed with that new array as normal.

**Edit:** I made a fail (not enough C0FFEE in my memory) and corrected thanks to the comment.

Comment: Actually it's a JSON object -> JSONObject -> Map.

Comment: Yes, I find that COFFEE has a very narrow value range -- easy to underflow and overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String elementName : elementNames)
  {
  JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(elementName);

    System.out.printf( "name=%s, value=%s\n",jsonobject.getString("name"),jsonobject.getString("value"));

  }
```

Comment: You're not accessing "current_data" first.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to parse JSON. Anyway, if you decide to follow as this is, try as :

You have a class like this:

```
class CurrentData{
  String name,timestamp,value;
  void print(){
    System.out.printf("name=%s, timestamp=%s, value=%s\n", name,timestamp, value);
  }
}
```

Now, change your for loop as follows:

```
 for (String elementName : elementNames)
  {
    if(!elementName.equals("current_data")){
    String value = objectInArray.getString(elementName);
    System.out.printf("name=%s, value=%s\n", elementName, value);
    }
    else{
    CurrentData obj=new CurrentData();// You can use array of objects declaring outside the loop as your need
    JSONObject curr_object=objectInArray.getJSONObject("current_data");
    obj.name=curr_object.getString("name");
    obj.timestamp=curr_object.getString("timestamp");
    obj.value=curr_object.getString("value");
    obj.print();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why iterate through elementNames vs just accessing `objectInArray.getJSONObject("current_data")`??

Comment: @HotLicks He/She wrote iteration, not for "current_data", but for other elements. Just look for "model_id" for example.

Comment: Except why iterate on Map elements?  You presumably want specific values and no sense going through values you don't want.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry, I didn't get you. What's wrong with it? May be he want all values.

Comment: But they come back in a jumble.  Each value has a meaning and would be associated with a particular program variable.  Iterating only makes sense if the only purpose is to dump the JSON contents.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Anyway, looking at his code, that is his purpose.

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject(jsonObj.toString());
JSONObject innerObject = outerObject.getJSONObject("Response");
JSONArray jsonArray = innerObject.getJSONArray("Asset");
for (int i = 0, size = jsonArray.length(); i < size; i++) {
    JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject currentData = objectInArray.getJSONObject("current_data");
    if (currentData != null) {
        String timestamp = currentData.getString("timestamp");
        String name = currentData.getString("name");
        String value = currentData.getString("value");
        // Assign above results to array elements or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: You should at least provide some explanation of what your code does.

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn - It's self-documenting.

Answer (score -2):

//nested jsonarray

```
FileReader inp=new FileReader("xyz.json");
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
Object obj=parser.parse(inp);
JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray) obj;
int len=jsonArray.size();
```

for(i:len)

{

JSONArray json1=(JSONArray) jsonArray.get(i);

Iterato iterator=json1.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext())

System.out.println(iterator.next());

}